# jQuery check wordpress_logged_in cookie

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies

there is a way to check wordpress cookie **wordpress_logged_in** using jquery?

I'm using cloudflare full caching, so there is no way to check if user is logged or not than this cookie, I tried to read it using jquery but seems protected and not visible, I can access it only using PHP.

Here is how I can read it right now :

```
$logged_in = 'no'; 
if (count($_COOKIE)) {
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $val) {
        if (preg_match("/wordpress_logged_in/i", $key)) {
            $logged_in = 'yes';
        }       
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a possiblity to check it simply by jquery, but I didn't find how.

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you want to check if user is logged in in cached pages, you have to use javascript and not a server-side script
I tried to check the wp-settings-time cookie from js, but it appears also after i've logged out, using the standard logout link in the admin bar, so how can that be a good solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't access to wordpress cookies named `wordpress_logged_in` using `js/jquery` just because it's flagged as [`HttpOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies):

> A secure cookie is only sent to the server with a encrypted request
>   over the HTTPS protocol... To prevent cross-site scripting (XSS)
>   attacks, HttpOnly cookies are inaccessible to JavaScript's
>   Document.cookie API; they are only sent to the server.

But since 3.0 wordpress add one more cookie named [wp-settings-{time}-[UID]](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies#WordPress_.3E_3.0) when user log in:

> WordPress also sets a few wp-settings-{time}-[UID] cookies. The number
>   on the end is your individual user ID from the users database table.
>   This is used to customize your view of admin interface, and possibly
>   also the main site interface.

And you can get this cookie using `js/jquery`. So, you can even get user ID from cookies.

Here is working js function for getting cookies and checking, if user is logged in:

```
function getLoggedInCookie() {
    var cookie = document.cookie.indexOf('wp-settings-time') !== -1;

    if(cookie){
        alert('Logged in');
    }else{
        alert('Not User');
    }
}
getLoggedInCookie();
```

jQuery solution will be to include [Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) to your wordpress theme/plugin and try to use it( may need in some modifications ).

**NOTE:**

Provided code will work with login forms, which use standart WordPress functions and endpoints, such as `http://{website-name}/wp-admin/` or `http://{website-name}/wp-login.php`. Third party plugins could not set cookies named `wp-settings-{time}-[UID]`.

Comment: When I use WooCommerce, which has its own login form, accepted answer doesn't work for me, because there are no cookies accessible by scripts set on login. The solution is to create such additional cookie on login and remove it on logout. It's shown how in this answer provided by Janos Szabo: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69814/check-if-user-is-logged-in-using-jquery/298840#298840

Comment: wp-settings-time cookie is not present

Comment: @FedericoSchiocchet It's there. Not sure how you checked. But without more details I can't help

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to know if a user is logged in you can check if the body element has class 'logged-in' i.e.

```
jQuery( 'body' ).hasClass( 'logged-in' )
```

WordPress adds this class to the body element if a user is logged in.

Comment: This does not work when the HTML page body is cached ..

Answer (score 2):

You can create ajax request to check if user logged in:

in functions.php:

```
function ajax_check_user_logged_in() {
    echo is_user_logged_in()?'yes':'no';
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_is_user_logged_in', 'ajax_check_user_logged_in');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_is_user_logged_in', 'ajax_check_user_logged_in');

function load_my_scripts()
{
    wp_localize_script('my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts');
```

in js:

```
var data = {
    action: 'is_user_logged_in'
};

jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if(response == 'yes') {
        // user is logged in
    } else {
        // user is not logged in
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar topic [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69814/check-if-user-is-logged-in-using-jquery)

This solution will work for you. Or you can add action on [login action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) and create js var for your file using `wp_localize_script()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, `wp_localize_script()` is a useful function. I use this, specifically:

```
wp_localize_script(
    'site-js',
    'siteVars',
    array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'isMobile' => (wp_is_mobile() ? true : false),
        'isHome' => (is_home() || is_front_page() ? true : false),
        'isSingle' => (is_single() ? true : false),
        'isLogged' => (is_user_logged_in() ? true : false),
    )
);
```

Then you can access it in your site script like `siteVars.isLogged` which will return the correct boolean value. Place this in your `functions.php` file. I prefer to place this in a function and execute it right after you enqueue your scripts.

You *might* be able to use a script such as [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) -- I've used that script to set/read cookie data through WP several times. Though the first method with `wp_localize_script()` is probably more reliable. If the cookie data is protected then the JS solution might not work. The PHP solution is a for-sure thing. You could even extend it to get the users role and user information.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your .HTACCESS File add this code.

It checks if Wordpress default logged in cookie is present & if so it sets cookie "hello".

If it detects "wordpress_logged_in" cookie is not present it removes/expires "hello" cookie.

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /wordpress_logged_in/">
        Header add Set-Cookie "hello;secure;path=/"
</If>

<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} !~ /wordpress_logged_in/">
       Header add Set-Cookie "hello;secure;Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 1963 07:28:00 GMT"
</If>
```

HttpOnly is not set on "hello" cookie therefore you can access it by javascript.